# How to use CalculationWindow in other class instead of MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, calculator

I am writing simple WPF Calculator app and for now I have implementented some of the basic features like addition, substraction etc. I have realised that my code looks awful and one class is resposible for everything. I was struggling to extract some of code, which is inside of every button click event method, to the other classes and methods, but without any result. I am aware of SOLID priciples, but as a beginner I have some difficulties in executing them, especially Single Resposibility Principle. CalculationWindow is TextBox name. I would be thankful, if you could tell me how to extract `CalculationWindow.Text = CalculationWindow.Text + "8"` to the other class.

**Some of those methods**

```
namespace CalculatorApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private double inputFirstDigit; 
        public string actionOperator;`

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NumberOneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalculationWindow.Text = CalculationWindow.Text + "1";
        }

        private void NumberTwoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalculationWindow.Text = CalculationWindow.Text + "2";
        }

        private void NumberThreeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalculationWindow.Text = CalculationWindow.Text + "3";
        }

        private void NumberFourButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalculationWindow.Text = CalculationWindow.Text + "4";
        }

        private void NumberFiveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalculationWindow.Text = CalculationWindow.Text + "5";
        }

        private void NumberSixButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalculationWindow.Text = CalculationWindow.Text + "6";
        }

        private void NumberSevenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalculationWindow.Text = CalculationWindow.Text + "7";
        }
```

**XML**

```
<Window x:Class="CalculatorApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CalculatorApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Calculator" Height="480" Width="350" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="85"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Save to file"/>
        </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Median"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Fibonacci Sequence"/>
    </Menu>
    <TextBox x:Name="CalculationWindow" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="29.333" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="70" Margin="15,15,15,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="310" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Button x:Name="BackspaceButton" Content="⌫" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,15,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="BackspaceButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="NumberSevenButton" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,15,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumberSevenButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="NumberFourButton" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,15,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumberFourButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="NumberOneButton" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,15,0,0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumberOneButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="NumberZeroButton" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,15,0,0" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Height="50" Click="NumberZeroButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="CButton" Content="C" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,15,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Height="50" Click="CButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="NumberEightButton" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,15,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumberEightButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="NumberFiveButton" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,15,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumberFiveButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="NumberTwoButton" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,15,0,0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumberTwoButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="NumberNineButton" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,15,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumberNineButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="NumberSixButton" Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,15,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumberSixButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="NumberThreeButton" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,15,0,0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumberThreeButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="CommaButton" Content="," HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,15,0,0" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="CommaButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="PlusMinusButton" Content="±" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,15,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="PlusMinusButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="DivisionButton" Content="/" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,15,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="DivisionButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="MultiplicationButton" Content="*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,15,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="MultiplicationButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="SubstractionButton" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,15,0,0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="SubstractionButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="AdditionButton" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,15,0,0" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="AdditionButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="SqrtButton" Content="√" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,15,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="SqrtButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="PercetangeButton" Content="%" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,15,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="PercetangeButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="ReciprocalButton" Content="1/x" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,15,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" Click="ReciprocalButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="ResultButton" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="=" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,15,0,0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="115" Click="ResultButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject as dependency the other class in the Constructor of the MainWindow() like:

```
private OtherClass otherClass;
public MainWindow(OtherClass otherClass)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.otherClass = otherClass;
    }
```

Then you can reference it everywhere in MainWindow.xaml.cs